# Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have been following the tutorial of Hyperledger Fabric Multi-Org setup and I was able to do it successfully. Now I want to customise it according to the name of the organization that I want to and I encountered below error when I was try to up the network. Hope someone could help me identify the problem. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Is this problem resolved or the cause known in the meantime? I encountered the same error - second run went through.

Comment: I am also facing the same error while setting up a network using raft. can someone please help as i'm stuck on this. didn't find any suitable answere anywhere else on the network too.

Comment: I get the same issue when I instantiate chaincode. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

it might be possible due to: TLS-connection problem, Connection problem (peer does not see orderer).

Check the peer's logs in debug mode.

```
docker logs <peer_container_id>
```

Comment: Hi, as per checking using docker ps. There is no orderer container up. I don't why there is none.

Comment: I can't seemed to start the orderer.

Comment: check container's list with "docker ps -a". then you can find Orderer container with exit-code (and check the logs). I have encountered the same error as yours. The reason was - network inaccessibility between peer's nodes and orderer.

Comment: @rusbro I also faced to the same situation and when I look for the logs it shows me like this.

Comment: ` Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp: could not load a valid signer certificate from directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/signcerts: stat /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/signcerts: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

I hit the similar error "context deadline exceeded".

My env is

- host: ubuntu 16,
- native docker: peer containers and an order container running on the host
- no virtual machine.
- Running commands on the host.

Change

```
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
peer channel join -o $ORDERER_ADDRESS -b $CHANNEL_BLOCK
```

to

```
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:7051
peer channel join -o $ORDERER_ADDRESS -b $CHANNEL_BLOCK
```

Fixed the error.

The way to locate the cause is checking if you can reach the addresses(orderer / peer) on the same terminal running the commands. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was some issue with the firewall (uft ubuntu).
I dissabled it an it worked.
However, I recommend you to check which ports you should open.